# How to add some actions in UserControl when losing reference to it?

Tags: c#, wpf, contentcontrol

In main window I have `ContentControl` to hold my `UserControl` (`myUC`) and converter.
**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel, Converter= 
    {local:ApplicationUserControlConverter}}">
</ContentControl>
```

**ApplicationUserControlConverter**:

```
public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    // Find the appropriate page
    switch ((ApplicationUserControl)value)
    {
        case ApplicationUserControl.Login:
            return new myUC();
    }
}
```

`ApplicationUserControl` is `enum`. To change `UserControl` I do this:

```
ViewModel.CurrentViewModel = ApplicationUserControl.Login;
```

So I lost reference to my previous `UserControl` and `GC` will eventually collect it. How to add some actions when I change my `UserControl`.
I thought about :

1. Create destructor. But it invokes only when `GC` work. And after [this](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/) article I don't think that it is good approach
2. Create method and somehow invoke it when I change `UserControl`, but is it good decision?

Comment: Use ViewModels and DataTemplates instead. This way you can change the ViewModel and keep the reference to it as well. Why do you want those actions?

Comment: @XAMlMAX I'll try to explain. Actually I want to create my own RichTextBox. I have a [Package] (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/IO/Packaging/Package.cs,fe33e1006e363b7e) class to hold images in memory and Uri to them. This class have a static dictionary to hold uri and memorystream. I wanted to remove this Uri's when user change UserControl, so he no longer needs this Uri's

Comment: Update your question, your comment is hard to read, for some reason the formatting didn't work for your URL. Ok so, you want to remove the URI so that would indicate that the image is already loaded. Do you load them from Web or HDD?

Comment: @XAMlMAX I want user to be able to load image from HDD and Web (drag and drop or copy). To store image and URI to this image I am using Package class. This class have a **static** dictionary. Now when I am changing UserControl images from previous UserControl still in memory. I want to remove them from this dictionary. I want behavior like this: when I "close" or lose reference to UserControl it will remove images (memorystream and URI) from Package class. Package class have methods for doing this.

Comment: Make the User Control be responsible for that, why would you want to handle that at application level? If UC needs to retrieve an image then let it handle that. What happens if you don't delete key from your static class? Would it affect the memory that much?

Comment: @XAMlMAX Yes, It will. If I don't delete key from this static dictionary it will consume memory throughout the work of application. I need something that will indicate that I have no access to this UserControl. I think I should make something like this [link](http://shrinandvyas.blogspot.com/2013/03/wpf-how-to-dispose-viewmodel-when.html) But I have to use MVVM pattern.

Comment: If you don't then please start using MVVM! What's this then->`ViewModel.CurrentViewModel = ApplicationUserControl.Login;` it will save all of this pain that you are going through now! I cannot stress enough how much it will help you! Beside the point of MvvM, try to use your UC to remove the link through the converter.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try to "cache" you old reference as property and add your Actions in "Set" section.

```
        public ApplicationUserControl OldValue
        {
            get => mOldValue;
            set 
            { 
                mOldValue = value; 
                //do stuff when your reference is changed...
            }
        }
        private ApplicationUserControl mOldValue;

        public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            OldValue = (ApplicationUserControl)value;

            switch (OldValue)
            {
                case ApplicationUserControl.Login:
                    return new myUC();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I found "Unloaded" event in UserControl and it invokes immediately after I change UserControl. So maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this as part of the converter. Just pass the converter a reference to the original UserControl and perform the necessary action before returning the new UserControl.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel, Converter= 
                {local:ApplicationUserControlConverter},
                ConverterParameter=<reference/path to current user control>}">
</ContentControl>
```

And inside the converter:

```
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // *** The 'parameter' argument contains the parameter. Convert to relevant type and call the required logic. ***
            ApplicationUserControl oldControl = (ApplicationUserControl)parameter;
            // Perform required logic...

            // Find the appropriate page
            switch ((ApplicationUserControl)value)
            {
                case ApplicationUserControl.Login:
                    return new myUC();
            }
        }
```